# How to I get Json.NET to throw an exception when JSON doesn't contain a property

Tags: json, json.net

How to I get Json.NET to throw an exception when JSON doesn't contain a property, which is a member of the object (during deserialization)?

ie, i'm looking for the inverse functionality to JsonSerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling.

Edit / Solution from DBC:
use Json.NET require all properties on deserialization
[Json.NET require all properties on deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29655502/json-net-require-all-properties-on-deserialization)

Comment: Are you looking for [Json.NET require all properties on deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29655502) and/or [Deserializing with Json.NET: Requiring a property/key to be present](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16292009)?

Comment: Thanks dbc - RequireObjectPropertiesContractResolver is the solution!  Perhaps this feature should added as a built in JsonSerializer Property?

Comment: Glad to help.  As for making it built-in, I've been thinking that Json.NET needs an easier way to plug in standard behaviors into a contract resolver beyond just subclassing.  Splitting out the [`NamingStrategy`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_NamingStrategy.htm) was a good first step.